# why minimum number in an array in an output shows error with loops

Tags: c++, arrays

I just started learning to code, so its very basic question. Below code gives some random number in `minimum` in output but gets right answer in `maximum`.

```
int array[6]={1,2,3,4,5,6};
   
int maximum=INT_MIN;

int minimum=INT_MAX;
  

for(int i=0;i<6;i++){

    if(array[i]>maximum){
         maximum=array[i];
    }
    else if(array[i]<minimum){
         minimum=array[i];
    }
}
cout<<maximum<<endl;


cout<<minimum<<endl;
```

Comment: How come minimum is gated by whether or not maximum is detected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used `else if` to update `minimum`, so `minimum` is not initialized when `maximum` is updated. You should remove the `else`.

```
for(int i=0;i<6;i++){

    if(array[i]>maximum){
         maximum=array[i];
    }
    if(array[i]<minimum){ // remove "else"
         minimum=array[i];
    }
}
```